# Flutter/Android: Filter apps that app chooser suggest me when I share file

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, share, share-plus

Im trying to build app for android with Flutter and Share_plus package. The app suppose to share files with WhatsApp and Telegram. When I press share button, native app chooser opens,
And suggest me non-relevant apps, like SMS sender or Instagram. I want the app chooser suggest me only two apps, Telegram and WhatsApp. I added these to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.package">
<queries>
    
    <package android:name="org.telegram.messenger" />
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />

</queries>
```

And still, native app chooser suggest me non relevant apps to share via. If there is a way show only apps that can handle sharing List of files, that's good enough.